# How can I share session among subdomains in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I have a website which has subdomains such as ali.sarahah.com but if a user logs in from *www.sarahah.com* then goes to *ali.sarahah.com* the session is not saved. After searching I added the following in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieDomain = ".sarahah.com"
});
```

I found out that .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie domain is still showing the subdomain and not the the domain and that session problem is still there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it by adding this to ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieDomain = ".yourdomain.com";
            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieSecure = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        })
```

The CookieSecure part is because my site moves between http and https in different pages.

Thank you :)

Comment: and how do you use the cookie on the other end? (sahara.com ) in your case

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to remove the leading `.` in the domain assignment as detailed in this [**GitHub**](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/993) issue:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Note that there is no leading .
        CookieDomain = "sarahah.com",
        CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.None
    });
```

See the [`CookieAuthenticationOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs) for the various properties.

Comment: The cookie with name .AspNetCore.Identity.Application still shows the subdomain... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for a solution to this problem using ASP.NET Core 2.0. You can set the cookie domain via the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` in your `ConfigureServices` method when adding the authentication services.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".yourdomain.com";
        });
```